# Best way to write streaming data to MongoDB database using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, streaming, real-time

I'm working on a project which has streaming iot data coming from aws kinesis data streams, I have a nodejs consumer reading from the stream .

I want to write the data to the database, but confused what is the best practice to do so, Batching data or make nodejs streams to write the data to database.

I have stored data in a 3 collection format:-

```
Devices: _id, name
Variables : device, _id,name
Values : _id, variable, value, time (this is a timeseries database)
```

Here is my sample payload:-

```
{
    'id': 232322,
    'topicPublished' : '/topic',
    'temp':23,
    'humidity':34,
    'windspeed':33
    'time' : epoch timestamp
    ...
}
```

I want to extract `temp,humidity and windspeed and other variables from payload` , store them in `variables collection` and `write the corresponding value to the values collection.`

Currently I'm batching data, pushing all incoming objects into an array and wait for the buffer size to get full. Is there any way where I can just stream write data to mongoDB and do the extraction process on the data streaming in nodejs streams.

But I'm having problem in the part where I extract the keys and store them in  variables collection and write corresponding values to values collection, and also whether or not is this a good approach that I mentioned above.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.